# CSS to make anchor hovers look like highlighter text

Tags: css, anchor

I've been struggling with this for days and just can't get it. Is it possible to get the hover state of a link to look like the attached picture? So it appears ilke a highlighter was used on the text and have the white space between the lines

http://krwilliams.com/lab/test/highlighterlinks.jpg

sorry it wouldn't let me attach the image.

Here is the closest I can get
http://krwilliams.com/lab/test/resources.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, turn off `float:left` on your A-tag.

Comment: THANK YOU! I can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: Good stuff. Please select this answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Comment: it won't let me with my current reputation